# Flutter AppBar (Actions) issue while using tabs

Tags: dart, flutter

I have encountered an issue while experimenting with flutter.
I have an AppBar with some Actions. 
One of these actions is a calendar widget. My desired behavior will be by the new date selection the data on my Scaffold to be changed accordingly. 
The issue is that, although I have managed to accomplished this behavior, the call to my API performed **twice**. I have identify that the issue was the **RefreshIndicator** that I had put in place (in order for the user to pull to refresh the page on demand), but I do not understand why...
For some reason when I change the date and consequently the data changed, it identify this as refresh state and then executes **_handleRefresh()**. The problem is, I still want to have the pull-down-to-refresh behavior.

Files on (tabView.dart file)
Scaffold's widget tree

```
RefreshIndicator(
     key: _modelRefreshKey,
     child: ListView.builder(
       itemCount: this._fetchedData?.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         if (this._fetchedData!= null) {
           final MyModel myModel  = this._fetchedData[index];
           return (index == 0)
               ? ResultsLayout(
                   model: myModel  ,
                   lastUpdateTxt: myModel.someTXT,
                 )
               : MyModelInheritedWidget(
                   model: myModel,
                   child: ModelCardLayout(),
                 );
         } else {
           return EmptyWidget();
         }
       },
     ),
     onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
   ),
```

Handle on refresh function

```
Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
    Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();
    this.getData().then((_) {
      completer.complete();
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

On select new date this function executes which refresh call again the data (hometab.dart file)

```
if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
      modelRefreshKey.currentState.widget.selectedDate = picked;
      modelRefreshKey.currentState?.getData();
    }
```

It is worth to point out the date method is located at where I create the tabs and the actual data to refresh is a part of a tab. I mention this in case it is some how related to my issue.

Any insights will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What this `modelRefreshKey.currentState.widget.selectedDate = picked;
` is doing ?

Comment: This sets the picked date from tabView.dart to another widget (hometab.dart) accessing via the key. This is my "working" implementation anyway. I could make it work in any other way. I tried to new that widget but it did not work. So I ended up with this. Probably there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a variable like the following to see if the app is waiting for an API response:

```
_isWaitingForResponse = false;

Future  getData() {
  if(_isWaitingForResponse) return;
  _isWaitingForResponse = true;
  //change _isWaitingForResponse on api's response
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. I will give it a go and I will let you know.

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. I will give it a go and I will let you know.

Comment: Holy moly!!! It actually works...Thanks very much... Although, it is kind of nasty way to do this, but for now it serves my purpose.

Comment: @Pan Yeah, it is a quick and dirty way, but it gets the job done, right? lol